# Concerning Ideals and invertible elements in a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is the problem that I have:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. Prove that $I=R$ if and only if $I$ contains some invertible element of the ring $R$.

Here is what I did:
Let $a\in I$, and $a$ is invertible. That will mean that $1\in I$, as $I$ includes $a^{-1}a$. And if $1\in I$, $I=R$, as for any $a\in R$, $a1=a$ and $1a=a$.

How can I prove the second part of the `if and only if`(i.e. prove that if $I=R$, then $I$ or $R$ includes invertible element)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**($\Rightarrow$)** Suppose $I=R$, then $1\in R$ which is an invertible element (unit).

**($\Leftarrow$)** We need to show that $1\in I$, as if this happens, then by definition of ideal. $1.a\in R$ i.e. every $a\in R$ implies $a\in I$. Thus $I\subseteq R$

**Case I:** $1\in R$. By definition of ideals $I=R$

**Case II:** If $a$ is a unit in R and $a\in I$. Then $1=a^{-1}a\in I$. Again by above statement $I=R$

Comment: My concern is that the problem tells that the ring is commutative. Where is that information used here ?

Comment: @khajvah commutativity is superfluous. A right/left/two sided ideal (of a ring with identity) is the whole ring iff it contains a unit. This proof shows why. Are you not convinced? of course it is healthy to check for sure if it's really not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If $I = R$, then $R$ contains unity, which is its own inverse, so $I$ contains an invertible element.

Comment: Well, that does work but I doubt that is what my professor wants. Can you think of a way(if there is) to prove that there is an invertible element which is not 1?

Comment: The reason I think so is because it gives extra information that isnt used (the ring is commutative)